# A website made in Prestashop is not working

Tags: prestashop

I have a problem with loading my website which is made with Prestashop. 4 or 5 months ago it was working fine, but today when I tried to open it it gives the me message "Unable to open file" or sometimes it gives me a server error.

I have already tested a die('999') when the index file is loading. When refreshing it, it gives me the result 999 instead of the message "unable to open the file". I don't know what happened to my website.

Comment: This really isn't enough information to be able to help you out. In order to see what the problem is we'd need to see the code that's failing. Also helpful would be any recent changes you've made to the site or the server.

Comment: PrestaShop Community Manager here. In order to identify the issue, you'll want to provide the following information: Version #, Specific error message, Hosting provider, and what recent changes you have made. Thanks.